# Sitemap file location

Tags: file, location, sitemap

I have developed a sitemap index and other sitemaps in cakephp on my website.
Currently the sitemap index is called using the URL **http://mysitename/sitemap** and not **http://mysitename/sitemap.xml**
Would it be possible for the search engines to understand the sitemap index location?

Answer (score 4):

You should define the location of your [sitemap file in your robots.txt](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php#submit_robots) file. Just include a line like this in your robots.txt file:

```
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap
```

If you do this, you can call it whatever you want and the major search engines will be able to locate it.